# Bootstrap datepicker not working with Angular validation

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using twitter boostrap datepicker : https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io

My code is :

```
<form name = "myForm" class = "form-container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="date">Status Date</label>
    <input data-provide="datepicker" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" 
           ng-model="sc.addColDate" required>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sc.addDateCol()" 
            ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid || myForm.$pending" data-dismiss="modal">
      Add
    </button>
  </div>
</form><!--Form end -->
```

My problem is that the `Add` button is disabled even after I have selected some date.

Comment: Instead of myForm.$pending use myForm.date.$error.required

Comment: You can check which one of the two criteria returns true. Try to remove the required attribute from input. If it's still disabled, then the pending criteria is the cause. Maybe the form returns undefined to model. You should create an mcve.

Comment: on change date. apply the value